# Nonlinear ODE Abel equation of the first kind

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

Edited: I have the following equation that represents a particular circuit. I am trying to get a solution that is practical for design purposes. I have went through some papers on Abel equations of the first kind, but I have not been able to get a reasonable solution. Thank you

$\frac{dy}{dx} + A_1y + A_3y^3 = F(x)$

Ok, let's say $F(x)$ is sinusoidal. It can be any waveform but let's say it is $F\sin(x)$ where F is just an amplitude.

$\frac{dy}{dx} + A_1y + A_3y^3 = F\sin(x)$

Answer (score -1):

Hint (Before edit): I assume $A_1$, $A_3$ and $F$ to be constants. Then this differential equation is separable.

$$\dfrac{dy}{F-A_1y-A_3y^3}=dx$$

The solution is not very nice. But if you can narrow the range of $y$ you could simplify it.

---

**EDIT**: In the case of a general $F(x)$ it is very likely that there is no simple closed form solution to the ODE. If you are trying to solve a practical problem you could try to look how much $F(x)$ does change in the practical range of values for $x$. It might be, that $F(x)\approx \text{const.}$ in the practical range of values.

Comment: I made an edit. $A_{1,3}$ are constants, but $F$ is not

Comment: So do you suggest I take the question down and resubmit

Comment: @Frank: Next time you should be more careful about stating your question. But in this case, you can leave it as it is. BTW check out the last line in my answer. As long as you do not provide the exact form of $F(x)$ is is almost impossible to write down a simple closed form solution to your ODE.

Comment: I made another edit. This is my first post on the math forum, so be patient with me. Thank you

Comment: Thank you sir. The duffing equation is second order. If I had an inductor in my circuit, then I would indeed have a duffing equation.

Comment: @Frank: Sorry, I totally forgot about the second derivative. What is your practical goal with the differential equation? Maybe a simulation would help you out.

Comment: I am using Keysight ADS for my simulations, and I can design using the tuning and optimization tools, but I am trying to get a more analytical model